# Matching values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I read a file that has 7 values with 7 different keys on each line and I put them in a dictionary. Some of the keys have '*' values and when I iterate through them I want to skip those in my operation. So, if my dictionary name is mydictionary can I do this:

```
    for entry in mydictionary:
        if entry != '*'
           do some work here
```

Comment: ...and the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your for loop with only grab the key and not the values.

You need to do something like this to get both the key and value.

```
for key, value in mydictionary.iteritems():
    if value != '*':
        # Do something
```

Something similar to this has been asked before. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python).